# Plotting a parabola using Tkinter

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, tkinter, canvas

I'm a beginner, and I have just written this basic code that simply plots a parabola in a graph.
Is it possible to make my code more efficient?

The process works by the creating lists of X and Y then adding range of numbers squared to the list Y and normal X to its list and then the function plot simply goes ahead and creates a range doubled + 2 the size ( because the previous `range(-size, size)` creates both the minus and positive values and a zero) and fills the `canvas.create_line(starting X location, starting Y location, ending X location, ending Y location)` statement and also creates a log.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import Tk

# Adding a Tk window
root: Tk = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry('640x480')   # Configuring the resolution

# Adding the canvas to put the graph on it
CanvasNo1 = tkinter.Canvas(root, width=640, height=480)
CanvasNo1.grid()


def draw_axis(canvas_object):   # a function in order to draw the horizontal and vertical lines and setting the scroll
    canvas_object.update()
    x_origin = canvas_object.winfo_width() // 2
    y_origin = canvas_object.winfo_height() // 2
    canvas_object.configure(scrollregion=(-x_origin, -y_origin, x_origin, y_origin))
    canvas_object.create_line(x_origin, 0, -x_origin, 0)
    canvas_object.create_line(0, y_origin, 0, -y_origin)


def parabola(number, size):  # Calculating the parabola
    result = number * number // size
    return result


def plot(canvas_object, size, color):  # The grand function to do the plotting process
    y_location = []
    x_location = []
    for each in range(-size, size+1):
        y_location.append(parabola(each, size))
        x_location.append(each)
    for each_of in range(0, size*2+2):
        if each_of <= size*2-1:
            canvas_object.create_line(x_location[each_of], -y_location[each_of], x_location[each_of+1],
                                      -y_location[each_of+1], fill=str(color))
            print('A line from X location of {} and Y location of {} to the X location of {} and Y location of {} was'
                  ' drawn, Color = {}'.format(x_location[each_of], y_location[each_of], x_location[each_of+1],
                                              y_location[each_of+1], color))
        else:
            break


draw_axis(CanvasNo1)
plot(CanvasNo1, 500, 'red')
CanvasNo1.mainloop()   # running the window
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating an empty list and appending the values to it, try using list comprehension.

so instead of

```
y_location = []
x_location = []
for each in range(-size, size+1):
    y_location.append(parabola(each, size))
    x_location.append(each)
```

try

```
y_location = [parabola(each,size) for each in range(-size,size+1)]
x_location = list(range(-size,size+1))
```

In general you can use a profiler to see which part of your code requires the largest amount of computing making it easier to improve the code.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html

Comment: The benefits of list comprehension over a for loop are small. I feel in most cases readability is more valuable than performance gain unless the date you are working with is massive.